# Using age and gender to search for ID numbers in a table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

In an interface where user records in a table can be searched.

The operator must be able to search by the age and/or the gender of the user(the record). However this must be done by using the ID number of the user captured.

This is possible, as the ID number can be broken down into usable data.

An ID number has 13 DIGITS:

eg. 6911205062080

Which can be broken down as follows:

YYMMDDSSSSCAZ

Where (YYMMDD) refers to date. 20 November 1969 is shown as 691120

(SSSS) refers to gender. Females are assigned numbers in the range 0000-4999 and males from 5000-9999

CAZ also carries meaning however they are not relevant to the context of the question. `

The user can choose to search All ages, or select from three age brackets:

A:18-38, B:39-59, C:60 upwards.

-They can select one option[ A or B or C]

-Or They can select two options[A and B,A and C or B and C],

-Or They can select all 3 options[A and B and C], meaning all of them)

This means that if they op **not** to search all of the age groups, an array containing their selection gets posted.

When selecting gender:

-They can search all genders[Male & Female]

-Or Choose one option [Either Male or Female]

The data gets sent to me and now I have to manipulate the data to return the correct records.

Now I know I have to use substrings. The ID field is stored as character varying however to establish the age I would have to substring the (YYMMDD) part and cast it to a date in order to correctly compare it, and the (SSSS) would have to be cast to an integer to establish if it is smaller than 5000

This is my code so far:

```
if($_POST['gender'] == 'all'){
    $gender="";
}elseif($_POST['gender'] == 'male'){
    $gender = " and userIDNumber = "."ESTABLISH ALL ID's THAT ARE MALE";
}elseif($_POST['gender'] == 'female'){
    $gender = " and userIDNumber = "."ESTABLISH ALL ID's THAT ARE FEMALE";
}

$age = "";
if($_POST['radioAge'] == 'select'){
    $branches = " and userIDNumber in (SELECT A WAY TO FIND OUT HOW TO ESTABLISH THE AGES THAT FALL IN THE GROUPS SPECIFIED BY THIS ARRAY in(".  implode(",", $_POST['age_group']).")) ";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE status='Active'".$gender.$age;
```

Using PHP and SQL, how would I go about using the posted gender selections and age selections to find the correct ID numbers and as a result, the correct records?

Comment: Can't you just store relevant data in separated columns, like `sex` and `birthDate`?

Comment: @Mattea That would be ideal, however I do not get to decide.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't try to store more than one piece of information in a single column.  You run into problems like this.  Also you won't be able to sort the list easily based on Date Of Birth or gender, and what happens if you get more than 5000 women registering?  You'll be far better off if you store gender, DOB, etc in separate columns with the appropriate datatype.

Comment: @AlbertusBrandVenter you might even get this to work, but I fear that with many records, not having a suitable index, it'll perform quite poorly.

Answer (score 1):

for the gender try something like this:

```
if($_POST['gender'] == 'all'){
    $gender="";
}elseif($_POST['gender'] == 'male'){
    $gender = "and CONVERT(SUBSTR(userIDNumber, 6, 4), INTEGER) < 5000";
}elseif($_POST['gender'] == 'female'){
    $gender = "and CONVERT(SUBSTR(userIDNumber, 6, 4), INTEGER) >= 5000";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to extract the information from the ID-s for the year part:
You need to use substring and string contatenation for this.
After that you need convert it to date and use the now() function to get the date difference. SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2011-10-02', '2012-01-01');
Finaly you need to create between branches like this:

```
 ... where  DATEDIFF(year, '2011-10-02', now()) between 18 and 38 ...
```

Gender:
Same way, extract the information from id with substring, cast it to numeric.

```
... where CAST(substring(ID) as numeric) <5000 --female
```

You also need to create the AND , OR operators.